# Write to existing .txt files - Escribir en archivos .txt ya existentes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Why does writing to a .txt file at first delete existing characters?
sorry for my ignorance, I haven't been programming for a long time.

```
Alabama[edit]
Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
Florence (University of North Alabama)
Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]
Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]
Troy (Troy University)[2]
Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[3][4]
Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]

f =open('university_towns.txt',"r+")
f.write('T\n')
f.close()

T
bama[edit]
Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
Florence (University of North Alabama)
Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]
Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]
Troy (Troy University)[2]
Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[3][4]
Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

to append to a file you need to use "open" with 'a+' instead of 'r+' (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open))

so in your case:

```
f =open('university_towns.txt',"a+")
f.write('T\n')
f.close()
```